# print Count of String type time entries group by hour

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I have a dataframe df with column time as a string.

[image]

I want to get a count of these entries grouped hourly.

for example how many time entries are there between every hour from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a string, you can slice the hour part and `value_counts`:

```
out = df['Time'].str[:2].value_counts(sort=False)
```

Or:

```
out = df.groupby(df['Time'].str[:2]).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the hour of this column using something like this:

```
df.groupby(df.Time.dt.hour).count()
```